# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Dynamic Pivot/Unpivot with (moving) Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, dynamic-pivot

I have posted a pivot question before and it was answered. However, this particular case requires dates as the headers and the dates will change (and be unknown) each time the pivot is generated. I believe I need dynamic pivot/unpivot based on a few samples but I cannot figure the syntax out.

Here is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PhaseFlowChart](
    [pfckey] [int] NULL,
    [hourlykey] [bigint] NULL,
    [daykey] [bigint] NULL,
    [weekkey] [int] NULL,
    [monthkey] [int] NULL,
    [bbkey] [int] NULL,
    [Day] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Date] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Bull Bear Gap] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Monthly] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Weekly] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Daily] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hour 1] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hour 2] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hour 3] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hour 4] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hour 5] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hour 6] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hour 7] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I do not need any of the 'key' columns in the output. Therefore here is a simple select on the table:

```
select [DAY],[Date],[Bull Bear Gap],[Monthly],[Weekly],[Daily],[Hour 1],[Hour 2],[Hour 3],[Hour 4],[Hour 5],[Hour 6],[Hour 7] 
from PhaseFlowChart
order by pfckey asc
```

Here is the output from the above:

[image]

I want the output (dynamic pivot/unpivot?) to look like this (and again, the dates will be different each time this is generated which is daily):

[image]

Finally, I found this sql on the web but after days of manipulating the syntax I cannot figure out how to port it to meet my needs.

```
CREATE TABLE #yt
    ([ID] int, [expense] int, [revenue] int, [date] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO #yt
    ([ID], [expense], [revenue], [date])
VALUES
    (1, 43, 45, '2012-12-31 00:00:00'),
    (2, 32, 32, '2013-01-01 00:00:00'),
    (3, 64, 56, '2013-01-31 00:00:00'),
    (4, 31, 32, '2013-03-03 00:00:00')

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(c.col+'_'+convert(varchar(10), #yt.date, 110)) 
                    from #yt
                    cross apply
                    (
                      select 'expense' col union all
                      select 'revenue'
                    ) c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id,' + @cols + ' 
            from
            (
              select id, 
                col+''_''+convert(varchar(10), date, 110) new_col, 
                value
              from #yt
              unpivot
              (
                value
                for col in (expense, revenue)
              ) un
            ) src
            pivot 
            (
                sum(value)
                for new_col in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

Any/all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to `UNPIVOT` our columns and use `DENSE_RANK()` to give you something to pivot on later. Put this result into a temp table so that you can get a comma seperated list of the `DESNSE_RANK` columns. Then create a `UNION` so that `Day` and `Date` are part of the same column as what was unpivoted. This can be put in a global temp table for use in the dynamic SQL. Create a variable that will store the list of columns and build the dynamic SQL and execute it.

A full example (obviously don't go dropping the `PhaseFlowChart` table)

```
-- pre-cleanup
IF OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[PhaseFlowChart]') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE [dbo].[PhaseFlowChart]
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tmp
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##tmp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE ##tmp
GO

-- setup table and data
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PhaseFlowChart](
    [pfckey] [int] NULL,
    [hourlykey] [bigint] NULL,
    [daykey] [bigint] NULL,
    [weekkey] [int] NULL,
    [monthkey] [int] NULL,
    [bbkey] [int] NULL,
    [Day] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Date] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Bull Bear Gap] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Monthly] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Weekly] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Daily] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hour 1] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hour 2] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hour 3] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hour 4] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hour 5] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hour 6] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Hour 7] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].PhaseFlowChart 
    ([Day], [Date], [Bull Bear Gap], Monthly, Weekly, Daily, 
        [Hour 1], [Hour 2], [Hour 3], [Hour 4], [Hour 5], [Hour 6], [Hour 7])
VALUES
('MON', '20130101', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1', 'P1'),
('TUE', '20130102', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2', 'P2'),
('WED', '20130103', 'P3', 'P3', 'P3', 'P3', 'P3', 'P3', 'P3', 'P3', 'P3', 'P3', 'P3'),
('THU', '20130104', 'P4', 'P4', 'P4', 'P4', 'P4', 'P4', 'P4', 'P4', 'P4', 'P4', 'P4'),
('FRI', '20130105', 'P5', 'P5', 'P5', 'P5', 'P5', 'P5', 'P5', 'P5', 'P5', 'P5', 'P5'),
('SAT', '20130106', 'P6', 'P6', 'P6', 'P6', 'P6', 'P6', 'P6', 'P6', 'P6', 'P6', 'P6'),
('SUN', '20130107', 'P7', 'P7', 'P7', 'P7', 'P7', 'P7', 'P7', 'P7', 'P7', 'P7', 'P7')
GO

-- unpivot the columns into 'categories'
SELECT [Day], [Date], [Value], [Category], 
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CAST([Date] AS DATE)) dr 
INTO #tmp
FROM PhaseFlowChart pfc
UNPIVOT (
    Value FOR Category IN ([Bull Bear Gap], Monthly, Weekly, Daily, 
                            [Hour 1], [Hour 2], [Hour 3], [Hour 4], 
                                [Hour 5], [Hour 6], [Hour 7])

) upiv

-- create a global temp table for use later
SELECT *
INTO ##tmp
FROM (
      -- union data into single category column
    SELECT 'Day' Category, [Day] Value, dr, 1 o FROM #tmp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Date' Category, [Date] Value, dr, 2 o FROM #tmp
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [Category], Value, dr, 3 o FROM #tmp
) t

-- get a comma seperated list of columns for the PIVOT
DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(MAX) = 
STUFF(CAST((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(dr)
       FROM (
           SELECT DISTINCT dr
           FROM #tmp
       ) t
       ORDER BY dr
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
      ) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),1,1,'')

-- create and execute the sql
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX) = '
    SELECT Category, ' + @cols + '
    FROM ##tmp
    PIVOT (
        MAX([Value])
        FOR dr IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) piv   
      ORDER BY o, CASE Category 
                    WHEN ''Daily'' THEN 4
                    WHEN ''Weekly'' THEN 3
                    WHEN ''Monthly'' THEN 2
                    WHEN ''Bull Bear Gap'' THEN 1
                    ELSE 5 END, Category
'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: T I brilliant, just what I needed thank you. In addition to using this I  will study your SQL to improve my pivot, unpivot and dynamic sql skills. Thank you, I really appreciate it.

Comment: T I - Sorry one last question. It is all working well except the date oriented columns are not in oldest to newest, left-to-right order. I tried fiddling with an order by statement but have not yet figured it out. How would I get the date columns to display oldest farthest to the left and most recent farthest to the right? Thanks!

Comment: try placing an `ORDER BY` on the query for `@cols` just after `FROM #tmp`

Comment: I did. Like this 'FROM #tmp order by dr asc' but then I received this error 'ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.'

Comment: Just to clarify it looks like the order from your query is by alpha of numeric items. So it looks like...[1],[10],[11], etc. Maybe I need another column in #tmp to be able to sort it?

Comment: I think the problem here is that your dates are currently `varchar`? If so ignore my `ORDER BY` comment and change the `DENSE_RANK` to `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CAST([Date] AS DATE))`. I have edited answer with this change

Comment: T I the 'DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CAST([Date] AS DATE))' returned similar results as before. Your solution is so close to what I need. I hope we can make this work. I have no issue changing the dates in the original table from varchar to date. However, not sure that will fix the problem. Would it help if we added a key to sort by ? I tried a few things but nothing is fixing the column sorting just yet. thx again.

Comment: @FrankZappa OK I have edited the query to get `@cols` to specify the ordering, hopefully this works.

Comment: @ T I - That's it! You did it! Awesome. This is exactly what is needed. Thank you very much.